Zammad google callback redirecting to another website (bet8k)
I have an instalation of Zammad 5.2.x made with docker compose and actualy when we try to add an account in channels-google, after the consent screen finishes it goes to an outside url instead of back to zammad.
Someone knows what could be? Can be a malware? and if yes how could we solve this?
Thank you in advance.
I tried restart Zammad some times and restart but the problem continues.
It should go back to zammad with the google account added.
